# Bind rows of the dataframes in a list with the same name

Tags: r, list, dataframe, tidyverse, purrr

Apologies in advance if this has been answered already. I have the following list of dataframes.

```
 my_list <- list(a = data.frame(a1 = c(1,2), b1 = c(3,4), c1 =c(5,6)),
                 b = data.frame(b1 = c(1,2,3)),
                 a = data.frame(a1 = c(11,21), b1 = c(31,41), c1 =c(51,61)),
                 b = data.frame(b1 = c(12,22)))
```

How could I bind the rows of all the dataframes in my list with the same name using purr? In this example the desired result is a list with two dataframes a and b.

```
list(a = bind_rows(data.frame(a1 = c(1,2), b1 = c(3,4), c1 =c(5,6)),
                   data.frame(a1 = c(11,21), b1 = c(31,41), c1 =c(51,61))),
     b = bind_rows(data.frame(b1 = c(1,2)),
                   data.frame(b1 = c(12,22))))
```

How could I generalise with a bind_rows solution for list elements with the same name. Thanks!

Comment: `my_list %>% split(names(.)) %>% map(bind_rows)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `==`

```
names(my_list) %>% 
     unique %>% 
     map(~ my_list[names(my_list)==.x] %>% 
       bind_rows)
#[[1]]
#  a1 b1 c1
#1  1  3  5
#2  2  4  6
#3 11 31 51
#4 21 41 61

#[[2]]
#  b1
#1  1
#2  2
#3  3
#4 12
#5 22
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `tapply` with `bind_rows`, pass `names(my_list)` as the *INDEX* (or group variable):

```
tapply(my_list, names(my_list), dplyr::bind_rows)

#$a
#  a1 b1 c1
#1  1  3  5
#2  2  4  6
#3 11 31 51
#4 21 41 61

#$b
#  b1
#1  1
#2  2
#3  3
#4 12
#5 22
```

Or another option, `split` the list first and then `map` through each group and `bind_rows` (didn't notice @alistaire has provided this option in the comment, but will keep this option in the answer for completeness unless argued against):

```
library(purrr)

split(my_list, names(my_list)) %>% map(dplyr::bind_rows)
# could also use baseR solution as from @Rich Scriven 
# split(my_list, names(my_list)) %>% map(do.call, what='rbind')

#$a
#  a1 b1 c1
#1  1  3  5
#2  2  4  6
#3 11 31 51
#4 21 41 61

#$b
#  b1
#1  1
#2  2
#3  3
#4 12
#5 22
```

Comment: Very nice.  Also doable with `rbind` if we do `tapply(my_list, names(my_list), do.call, what = "rbind")`

Comment: Many thanks for this. I will mark it as useful given it does the job. However this is not using purr and my main ask was to understand how to do this with map or some other purr function.

Comment: AFAIK, there's not a corresponding function in `purrr` equivalent to `tapply` or `split` which is essentially group then apply. So can't really think of a pure purrr way to do this.