# Combine list of monthly named list of dataframes into one yearly name list of dataframes using purrr

Tags: r, purrr

Every month I create a named list of dataframes with the same names.

I would like to use purrr to combine the lists of a number of months as to get one list of dataframes containing in each dataframe the data for all months.

(in the repexp below the data in the different dataframes is the same for all months, that's obviously not the case in the real data)

```
#create some data

method1 <- read.csv(text="input,output,result
A,a,1
A,b,3
B,b,8
A,d,11
") 

method2 <- read.csv(text="rainy_days, count
1,4
3,3
5,8
7,10
") 


method3 <- read.csv(text="in,out,rslt
A,a,6
A,b,5
B,b,1
A,d,12
") 

method4 <- read.csv(text="input,output,result
A,a,1
C,c,4
")
```

The monthly named lists

```
month1 <- list(method1=method1,method2=method2,method3=method3)
month2 <- list(method1=method1,method2=method2,method3=method3)
month3 <- list(method1=method1,method3=method3)
month4 <- list(method1=method1,method2=method2,method3=method3, method4=method4)

# > str(month1)
# List of 3
# $ method1:'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ input : chr [1:4] "A" "A" "B" "A"
# ..$ ouput : chr [1:4] "a" "b" "b" "d"
# ..$ result: int [1:4] 1 3 8 11
# $ method2:'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ input : chr [1:4] "A" "A" "B" "A"
# ..$ ouput : chr [1:4] "a" "b" "b" "d"
# ..$ result: int [1:4] 4 3 8 10
# $ method3:'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ input : chr [1:4] "A" "A" "B" "A"
# ..$ ouput : chr [1:4] "a" "b" "b" "d"
# ..$ result: int [1:4] 6 5 1 12
```

I would like to replace

```
current_year_method1 <- bind_rows(month1[[1]], month2[[1]],month3[[1]],month4[[1]])
current_year_method2 <-bind_rows(month1[[2]], month2[[2]],month4[[2]])
current_year_method3 <-bind_rows(month1[[3]], month2[[3]],month3[[3]],month4[[3]])
current_year_method4 <-bind_rows(month4[[4]])

year_all_data <- list(method1=current_year_method1,method2=current_year_method2,method3=current_year_method3,method4=current_year_method4)
```

with a more generic solution starting from a list of months.

Some workaround to get there is flatten the list and then use one of the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102179/bind-rows-of-the-dataframes-in-a-list-with-the-same-name)

```
year_list_flat <- flatten(list(month1,month2,month3,month4))

all_year <- year_list_flat %>% split(names(.)) %>% map(bind_rows)

# > str(all_year)
# List of 4
# $ method1:'data.frame':   16 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ input : chr [1:16] "A" "A" "B" "A" ...
# ..$ ouput : chr [1:16] "a" "b" "b" "d" ...
# ..$ result: int [1:16] 1 3 8 11 1 3 8 11 1 3 ...
# $ method2:'data.frame':   12 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ input : chr [1:12] "A" "A" "B" "A" ...
# ..$ ouput : chr [1:12] "a" "b" "b" "d" ...
# ..$ result: int [1:12] 4 3 8 10 4 3 8 10 4 3 ...
# $ method3:'data.frame':   16 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ input : chr [1:16] "A" "A" "B" "A" ...
# ..$ ouput : chr [1:16] "a" "b" "b" "d" ...
# ..$ result: int [1:16] 6 5 1 12 6 5 1 12 6 5 ...
# $ method4:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ input : chr [1:4] "A" "C"
# ..$ ouput : chr [1:4] "a" "c"
# ..$ result: int [1:4] 1 4
```

but then I lose the possibility to use the name of the monthly file as an indicator variable due to the use of flatten.

Conceptually it is also different because you combine first all lists into a single list and next combine the dataframes.

Is there an elegant way that does not use flatten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, one possible solution is to use the `plyr` packages in combination with the `purrr` package. I suppose this part as "given":

```
month1 <- list(method1=method1,method2=method2,method3=method3)
month2 <- list(method1=method1,method2=method2,method3=method3)
month3 <- list(method1=method1,method3=method3)
month4 <- list(method1=method1,method2=method2,method3=method3, method4=method4)
```

Which we can combine to a named list (in your monthly run code you would just increment a list item):

```
d <- list(month1 = month1, month2 = month2, month3 = month3, month4 = month4)
```

this gives you a two level deep, named list. It is important for the list to be named after method on the lowest and month on the highest level for the `ldply` function to work (names becomes new id field):

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)

# first call use purr to transform sub lists do df with method as new column name
ir <- purrr::map(d, ~plyr::ldply(.x, .id ="method")) %>% 
    # secondly convert the new one level list to one df with month as new column
    plyr::ldply(.id = "month")

    month  method input output result
1  month1 method1     A      a      1
2  month1 method1     A      b      3
3  month1 method1     B      b      8
4  month1 method1     A      d     11
5  month1 method2     A      a      4
6  month1 method2     A      b      3
7  month1 method2     B      b      8
(some lines where omitted)

# you can group and split by grouping into lists
ir %>% 
    # build the grouping to split by into list and use group_split
    dplyr::group_by(method) %>% 
    dplyr::group_split()

[[1]]
# A tibble: 16 x 5
   month  method  input output result
   <fct>  <fct>   <chr> <chr>   <int>
 1 month1 method1 A     a           1
 2 month1 method1 A     b           3
 3 month1 method1 B     b           8
 4 month1 method1 A     d          11
 5 month2 method1 A     a           1
 6 month2 method1 A     b           3
 7 month2 method1 B     b           8
 8 month2 method1 A     d          11
 (lines and further listt items omitted)
```

**EDIT**

since the input data was altered from list of dfs with the same colums to list of dfs with diferent columns, here goes one aproach using the logic show above. This time though we have to transform all columns to character for it to work, meaning the output will be all character as well, but that should be easily solvable given the data structure. The modification to the first version is tranforming all dfs to long format, so that the row names become a new column and we have only one column of values. In the end we have to make the data wider to get the original format. All we need is a little helper to identify df rows, which is the row number:

```
res <- purrr::map(d, ~purrr::map(.x, ~ dplyr::mutate(.x,
                                                     dplyr::across(dplyr::everything(), ~ as.character(.x)), 
                                                     rn = dplyr::row_number()) %>% 
                                           tidyr::pivot_longer(-rn)) %>%
                                           plyr::ldply(.id = "method")) %>% 
    plyr::ldply(.id = "month") %>%  
    dplyr::group_by(method) %>% 
    dplyr::group_split() %>%
    purrr::map(~ .x %>% 
                     tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value") %>%
                     dplyr::select(-rn))
# name the list items cording to unique method colum of list item dfs
names(res) <- purrr::map_chr(res, ~ unique(as.character(.x$method)))

res

$method1
# A tibble: 16 x 5
   month  method  input output result
   <fct>  <fct>   <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
 1 month1 method1 A     a      1     
 2 month1 method1 A     b      3     
 3 month1 method1 B     b      8     
 4 month1 method1 A     d      11    
(many lines and other list item omitted)
```

Comment: thanks,  also an interesting solution with a function I never used before (ldply). I will have a look into that one, too

Comment: @Lod have a look as the edit of my answer... possibly this solves your problem

Comment: Great! That's indeed the outcome I am looking for. It looks complicated but I guess splitting and combining is the only way given what I need is acroos different lists. Thanks, I will have a in in-depth look to try to fully understand the proposed approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `bind_rows` and `map(x, bind_rows)`

```r
library(tidyverse)
  
# create some data

method1 <- read.csv(text="input,output,result
A,a,1
A,b,3
B,b,8
A,d,11
") 

method2 <- read.csv(text="input,output,result
A,a,4
A,b,3
B,b,8
A,d,10
") 


method3 <- read.csv(text="input,output,result
A,a,6
A,b,5
B,b,1
A,d,12
") 

method4 <- read.csv(text="input,output,result
A,a,1
A,b,2
B,b,3
C,c,4
") 

# The monthly named lists

month1 <- list(method1=method1,method2=method2,method3=method3)
month2 <- list(method1=method1,method2=method2,method3=method3)
month3 <- list(method1=method1,method3=method3)
month4 <- list(method1=method1,method2=method2,method3=method3, method4=method4)

# for one of these lists, can bind_rows
bind_rows(month1, .id = "month")
#>      month input output result
#> 1  method1     A      a      1
#> 2  method1     A      b      3
#> 3  method1     B      b      8
#> 4  method1     A      d     11
#> 5  method2     A      a      4
#> 6  method2     A      b      3
#> 7  method2     B      b      8
#> 8  method2     A      d     10
#> 9  method3     A      a      6
#> 10 method3     A      b      5
#> 11 method3     B      b      1
#> 12 method3     A      d     12

# for a list of lists, bind rows within each element (methods in months), then bind again (months)
df <- lst(month1, month2, month3, month4) %>% 
  map(bind_rows, .id = "method") %>%   
  bind_rows(.id = "month")             
print(df)
#>     month  method input output result
#> 1  month1 method1     A      a      1
#> 2  month1 method1     A      b      3
#> 3  month1 method1     B      b      8
#> 4  month1 method1     A      d     11
#> 5  month1 method2     A      a      4
#> 6  month1 method2     A      b      3
#> 7  month1 method2     B      b      8
#> 8  month1 method2     A      d     10
#> 9  month1 method3     A      a      6
#> 10 month1 method3     A      b      5
#> 11 month1 method3     B      b      1
#> 12 month1 method3     A      d     12
#> 13 month2 method1     A      a      1
#> 14 month2 method1     A      b      3
#> 15 month2 method1     B      b      8
#> 16 month2 method1     A      d     11
#> 17 month2 method2     A      a      4
#> 18 month2 method2     A      b      3
#> 19 month2 method2     B      b      8
#> 20 month2 method2     A      d     10
#> 21 month2 method3     A      a      6
#> 22 month2 method3     A      b      5
#> 23 month2 method3     B      b      1
#> 24 month2 method3     A      d     12
#> 25 month3 method1     A      a      1
#> 26 month3 method1     A      b      3
#> 27 month3 method1     B      b      8
#> 28 month3 method1     A      d     11
#> 29 month3 method3     A      a      6
#> 30 month3 method3     A      b      5
#> 31 month3 method3     B      b      1
#> 32 month3 method3     A      d     12
#> 33 month4 method1     A      a      1
#> 34 month4 method1     A      b      3
#> 35 month4 method1     B      b      8
#> 36 month4 method1     A      d     11
#> 37 month4 method2     A      a      4
#> 38 month4 method2     A      b      3
#> 39 month4 method2     B      b      8
#> 40 month4 method2     A      d     10
#> 41 month4 method3     A      a      6
#> 42 month4 method3     A      b      5
#> 43 month4 method3     B      b      1
#> 44 month4 method3     A      d     12
#> 45 month4 method4     A      a      1
#> 46 month4 method4     A      b      2
#> 47 month4 method4     B      b      3
#> 48 month4 method4     C      c      4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, it's not exactly what I am looking for but it could also be a starting point as it keeps both month and filename. I would like to keep a list with for each "method"-file a dataframe. So, the structure of all_year in my example but with an id column added in each dataframe.

Comment: You can use the .id argument to keep the filenames in a column like this fn %>% set_names(fn) %>% map_dfr(read_csv, .id = "filename") where fn is a string vector of filenames.

Comment: I have added the structure of the desired final list to the question
if I remove from `df <- lst(month1, month2, month3, month4) %>% 
   bind_rows(.id = "month")` the NA rows I am close, but I will have to check how this works out with the real data as some of the dataframes have thousands of rows.  It would certainly have the advantage of readability.

Comment: On the real data it gives an error `Error: Can't recycle `method1` (size 4) to match `method4` (size 2).` I adapted the example to reflect this aspect. The number of rows is not equal in all dataframes, resulting in the error.

Comment: My code still runs for me if you run it after month1, ... month4 are defined.

Comment: it runs but for many files with many columns it generates for every column that exists in one of the dfs a column in the resulting file (with NAs). For situations with few columns, I could use `group_split(method)' to split the file in a list of dfs, but for may files with many columns it is too spurious. For clarity I changed the column names in the different files.